# Copy all files from a folder to another one

Tags: copy, directory, stata

I want to copy all files from a folder to another one in Stata.

I have used the following code:

```
local dlist: dir "$dir" dirs "*"

foreach d of local dlist {

    local file: dir "$dir\"`d'"" files "*.dta"
    foreach f of local file{
       copy `f' "$dir/PROGRAMMATION/INITIALES"
    }   
}
```

However, Stata returns:

> invalid syntax

`$dir` is the actual directory where this do-file is located.

Comment: Personally I would just use the OS command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
global dir /Users/monkey/Downloads

local dlist: dir "$dir" dir "*"

foreach d of local dlist {
    local file: dir "$dir/`d'" files "*.dta"

    foreach f of local file {
       copy "$dir/`d'/`f'"  "/Users/monkey/testdir/`f'"
    }
}
```

Note that the code will `copy` all Stata dataset files contained in ***every sub-directory*** of `/Users/monkey/Downloads` to the directory `/Users/monkey/testdir/`.

If you just want to `copy` all Stata dataset files from `/Users/monkey/Downloads` to `/Users/monkey/testdir/` one loop will suffice:

```
global dir /Users/monkey/Downloads

local file: dir "$dir" files "*.dta"

foreach f of local file{
    copy "$dir`f'"  "/Users/monkey/testdir/`f'"
}
```

Comment: your code works perfectly as expected. In fact, i've forgotten to add the path in the copy command.